# ASCII - пустые символы

Tags: алгоритм, qt, qt5, шифрование, ascii

Всем привет! Сейчас я пишу программу-шифровщик, которая берет пароль и текст, а затем, определяя их ASCII-коды, создает третий по алгоритму XOR. На выходе получается ASCII-код, который затем преобразуется в char и приписывается к строке выхода.

Сейчас программа уже написана; но появилась проблема: я не знал о том, что все коды ASCII до 32 (т. е. 00100000 ) являются не символами, а кодами клавиш. Как мне это можно исправить? Может, есть другая система шифрования, где все коды - символы?
[image: Таблица ASCII]

Привожу код, выполняющийся по нажатию кнопки (QT 5, закомментированный код - для отладки). textEdit - для ввода текста, textEdit_2 - для пароля, textEdit_3 - выход.

```
void Form::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int n1, n2;
    QString str, key, out, symbol, copy1, copy2;
    QChar copy3;
    str = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    key = ui->textEdit_2->toPlainText();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i ++)
    {
        copy3 = str [i];
        n1 = copy3.toLatin1();
        copy3 = key [i % key.length()];
        n2 = copy3.toLatin1();
        copy1 = QString::number(n1);
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j ++)
        {
            if (n1 % 2 == 1)
            {
                copy1 [j] = '1';
            }
            else
            {
                copy1 [j] = '0';
            }
            if (n2 % 2 == 1)
            {
                copy2 [j] = '1';
            }
            else
            {
                copy2 [j] = '0';
            }
            n1 /= 2;
            n2 /= 2;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j ++)
        {
            if (copy1 [j] != copy2 [j])
            {
                symbol [j] = '1';
            }
            else
            {
                symbol [j] = '0';
            }
        }
//        num = ((symbol[0] == '1')? 1 : 0) + ((symbol[1] == '1')? 2 : 0) + ((symbol[2] == '1')? 4 : 0) + ((symbol[3] == '1')? 8 : 0) + ((symbol[4] == '1')? 16 : 0) + ((symbol[5] == '1')? 32 : 0) + ((symbol[6] == '1')? 64 : 0) + ((symbol[7] == '1')? 128 : 0);
//        copy3 = num;
//        ui->textEdit_3->append("Коды: " + copy1 + " " + copy2 + " " + symbol + "\n" + "Символ: " + copy3);
        out = out + copy3;
    }
    ui->textEdit_3->append("\n" + out);
}
```

Comment: Ну гляньте в столбец отображаемых символов [тут](http://digitalchip.ru/uploads/proj_files/nokia1100/ascii-codes.pdf) - это устроит?

Comment: @Harry, так проблема в том, что код может быть не отображаемого символа - как в этом случае поступить, чтобы можно было не только зашифровать, но и расшифровать?

Comment: @Harry, нет, проблема с символом 00000000 - он мне все карты портит. Вот, после "Символ" в правой колонке (это не пробел!): https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xRXn.png

Comment: Base64 на ваши байты превратит даже нули в читаемые символы.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, а как в Qt перевести символ в эту систему кодировки?

Comment: @ЧижевскийДаниил QByteArray::toBase64 - первый (!) результат гугла

Comment: Что-то у меня ощущение, что это XY-проблема... Ну и какая разница, как **выглядит** зашифрованный текст? что его, человеку читать, что ли?

Comment: @Yfrry, так как выделить **пустой** символ для расшифровки? Так весь текст поедет)

Comment: Переходите к байтам, XOR все равно с ними работает, а не с символами

Comment: Замените на запись в шестнадцатеричном виде :)